# Retrofit + Okhttp cancel operation not working

Tags: android, httprequest, retrofit, okhttp, cancellation

I am using retrofit in my application like this

```
 final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
 okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new YourInterceptor());

            final OkClient okClient = new OkClient(okHttpClient);
            Builder restAdapterBuilder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
            restAdapterBuilder.setClient(okClient).setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)
                    .setEndpoint("some url");
            final RestAdapter restAdapter = restAdapterBuilder.build();


public class YourInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Request request = chain.request();

        if (request != null) {
            Request.Builder signedRequestBuilder = request.newBuilder();
            signedRequestBuilder.tag("taggiventorequest");
            request = signedRequestBuilder.build();
            request.tag();
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```

after sending request i am calling

```
okHttpClient.cancel("taggiventorequest");
```

but request is not cancelling i am getting the response from retrofit
dont know why it is not cancelling my request

I need volley like cancelation retrofit

Comment: Are you sure your request isn't finished before you call cancel?

Comment: yeah sure i got the response after 2 seconds of clicking cancel

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski when can i expect retrofit 2.0 version?

Answer (score 6):

As [Retrofit API Spec](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297), Canceling request will be included in version 2.0.

> cancel() is a no-op after the response has been received. In all other
>   cases the method will set any callbacks to null (thus freeing strong
>   references to the enclosing class if declared anonymously) and render
>   the request object dead. All future interactions with the request
>   object will throw an exception. If the request is waiting in the
>   executor its Future will be cancelled so that it is never invoked.

For now, you can do it by creating custom callback class which implements on Callback from retrofit.

```
public abstract class CancelableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private boolean canceled;
    private T pendingT;
    private Response pendingResponse;
    private RetrofitError pendingError;

    public CancelableCallback() {
        this.canceled = false;
    }

    public void cancel(boolean remove) {
        canceled = true;
    } 

    @Override
    public void success(T t, Response response) {
        if (canceled) {
            return;
        }
        onSuccess(t, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        if (canceled) {
            return;
        }
        onFailure(error);
    }

    protected abstract void onSuccess(T t, Response response);

    protected abstract void onFailure(RetrofitError error);
}
```

MyApi.java,

```
private interface MyApi {
    @GET("/")
    void getStringList(Callback<List<String>> callback);
}
```

In Activity or Fragment,

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Config.URL)
            .build();
MyApi service = restAdapter.create(MyApi.class);
CancelableCallback callback = new CancelableCallback<List<String>>() {
    @Override
    protected void onSuccess(List<String> stringList, Response response) {
        for (String str : stringList) {
            Log.i("Result : ", str);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFailure(RetrofitError error) {
        Log.e("Error : ", error.getMessage() + "");
    }
};

service.getStringList(callback);
```

To cancel your request, simple call

```
callback.cancel();
```

This is an simple example to cancel each request. You can handle (cancel, pause, resume) two or more request at the same time by creating callback manager class. Please take a look [that comment](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/297#issuecomment-97691904) for reference.

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: thanks for explanation, but in this case, you just ignore the response when the cancel hit. So, the executor still running in background.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the request is completed, from the docs:

http://square.github.io/okhttp/javadoc/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html#cancel-java.lang.Object-

> ```
> cancel
> ```
>
> public OkHttpClient cancel(Object tag)
>
> Cancels all scheduled or in-flight calls tagged with tag. Requests that are already complete cannot be canceled.

Comment: the request are not cancelling which still didnt send response
I am getting the response after clicking cancel button

Comment: OkHttp request not cancelling my on going calls.